# Laravel image doesn't display

Tags: laravel, image, storage

I'am using this code to display the image

```
@foreach($Phones as $clothe)
        @if($clothe->category=='Phones')
        <div class="card" style="width: 300px; display:inline-block; margin:20px;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ URL::asset('storage/images/'.$clothe->image)}} " width="100%"/>
```

the picture exist on storage\app\public\images but it doesn't display on my page, btw i've made the php artisan storage:link

Comment: can you inspect page and  show me full link of image

Comment: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/storage/images/a30_1606210965.jpg "

Comment: Have you tried with a preceeding slash? ```{{ asset('/storage/images/'.$clothe->image)}}```

Comment: yes, same problem

Comment: `dd(asset('/storage/images/'.$clothe->image))` and check the value

Comment: Try `src="/storage/images/{{ $clothe->image }}"`

Comment: nope , didn't work either

Comment: guys i really need your help i have to present this tommorow ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are having the same problem as me here is what to do :
delete the folder storage on public and retype the command "php artisan storage:link"

Answer (score 0):

add src="/ and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

check image available in folder `ProjectName/public/storage/images/a30_1606210965.jpg`

read this artical/link...

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-display-image-from-storage-folder-in-laravelexample.html

from above article

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/'.$clothe->image) }}" alt="" title="">
```

Comment: yes and the file exist in my images folder with the same name

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8001/storage/images/a30_1606210965.jpg ..... open this directly on browser its show or not check

Comment: clear cache and then try again....
`php artisan route:clear`
`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan view:clear`
`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan route:cache`

Comment: i get this error when i type php artisan route:cache https://imgur.com/a/j4d3utu

Comment: send folder image(visible directory) ... like public/storage/image

Comment: sorry but can you explain more ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/GLq219i check this image for  better understanding 

check this path public/storage ...

Comment: the path for the pictures is "htdocs\blog\storage\app\public\images not "public/storage" , could this be the problem ?

Comment: use this `php artisan storage:link` and check htdocs\blog\public\storage\images  create or not ....not show directly in Storage folder

Comment: when i use "php artisan storage:link" i get this "The "public/storage" directory already exists." and no it doesn't create a folder on stoarge

Comment: again check into this folder htdocs\blog\public\storage\images .... image  available or not ....

Comment: if image available then not need to run that command

Comment: what is your project link ?
 `http://localhost/storage/images/a30_1606210965.jpg`

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/a30_1606210965.jpg`
`http://127.0.0.1:8001/storage/images/a30_1606210965.jpg`

check image name so we can varify path its right or wrong so check according your url only change your image name

Comment: It worked, i ve deleted the folder storage on public and retype the command "php artisan storage:link" and worked

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working fine on my side.

.env

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
Php artisan config:clear
```

Upload image code

```
  $request->file('image')->store('image');
```

blade file

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$clothe->image) }}" alt="" title="">
```